# Can't access property in abstract class via sub class

Tags: php, model-view-controller, inheritance, abstract-class

I am trying to build an abstract base controller that will extend all other controllers. So far I have something like:

```
    abstract class BaseController {

     protected $view;
     protected $user;

     public function __construct() {
       $this->view = new View; //So a view is accessible to subclasses via $this->view->set();
       $this->user = new User; //So I can check $this->user->hasPermission('is_admin');
     }
     abstract function index();

    }

class UserController extends BaseController {

  public function index() {}

  public function login() {

  if($this->user->isLoggedin()) {
   redirect to my account
  }
  else {
      $this->view->set('page_title', "User Login");
      $this->view->set('sidebar', $sidebar); //contains sidebar HTML
      $this->view->set('content', $content); //build main page HTML
      $this->view->render();

}
}
}
```

The problem i get is I get errors like this:

```
Call to a member function set() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\program\core\controllers\admin.controller.php on line 44
```

If I put the $user and $views properties in the main controller (ie UserController), everything works fine. But I only want to set up these objects once (in the base controller) and not have to add `$this->view = new View;` in all my controllers.

**FIXED:** I overrode my constructors and I thought you couldn't call parent::__construct() on abstract classes.

Comment: Did you override the constructor in a way we dont see here and if so did you call parent::__construct()?

Comment: Your code works for me on my test case. You have overridden the __constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do should work. Make sure you aren't covering up your constructor in `UserController`. (i.e., if it has a constructor, it needs to call its parent constructor.)

Otherwise, do some debugging to see where `$this->view` is being reset.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. You are either overriding your `__construct()` method in `UserController`, or you are overridding the `view` field with something other than a `View` object.

What you have in this form would work.